# Web API IIS Requirements

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, asp.net-web-api

Does the ASP.NET Web API require any particular version of IIS to run? I'm interested in knowing for each version of Web API, e.g. if Web API 2.0 requires IIS7.5 and Web API 2.1 requires IIS8 for instance. I can't seem to find this information anywhere.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ASP.NET Web API is part of ASP.NET stack, and therefore is supported on all IIS releases if the targeting .NET Framework is supported also on that Windows version.

- First release of ASP.NET Web API (version 4.0.20710) and its patched version (4.0.30506) requires .NET 4, which covers all Windows versions starting from Windows XP. That means IIS 5.1 and above should support this release of Web API.
- Second release, called ASP.NET Web API 2 (version 5.0.0), and above (aka 2.1 and 2.2) requires .NET 4.5, which covers all Windows versions starting from Windows Vista. That means IIS 7.0 and above should support ASP.NET Web API 2.*.

References:

The NuGet Packages:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi

.NET Framework 4 Download (check System Requirements):
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22833

.NET Framework 4.5 Download (check System Requirements):
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

IIS Windows Matrix:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224609

Comment: Good answer, but can you back up your facts with links to official sources please?

Comment: The information spans in multiple sources, and requires experience with .NET Framework, NuGet, IIS, and Windows. Thus, there is no single article to document them all.

Comment: All right, your answer will have to do then. :) Thanks!

Comment: If there was a single document referencing them all, then there would have been no need for the question !